# No Suitable Driver Found Error after deploying a war file on Openshift

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, driver, openshift

Hi all I know that the `No Suitable Driver Found Error` for openshift thread has been solved before but , [after the multiple errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21348850/connecting-a-tomcat-project-app-with-mysql-on-openshift) i get when i deploy a project from eclipse( a maven one) i have tried to deploy the war file ( a dynamic web project) on webapp folder and then just git add , commit and push and finally i got my servlet running But i cant communicate with mysql database I have added the mysql_connector to the web-inf/lib/ folder but still nothing ! Like i said i am on a dynamic web project so i cant add the dependencies to the pom.xml file Does anyone have a idea?

My java file:

```
import java.io.*;

//import java.util.*;
//import javax.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

//krijojme nje klase qe zgjaton superclassen HttpServlet
public class DBConnection extends HttpServlet {
    public static final String MYSQL_USERNAME = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
    public static final String MYSQL_PASSWORD = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");
    public static final String MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");
    public static final String MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
    public static final String MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME = "jbossews";
  /**
     * kjo ketu nuk e di per cfare perdoret po duhet vene 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //krijojme nje metode te klases HttpServlet me emrin service 
    //dhe qe merr 2 parametra nje reqyest dhe nje response 
    //si dhe hedh disa lloje gabimesh si psh input out exeption 
    //si dhe servlet Exception
public void service(HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response)
  throws IOException, ServletException{
    //ketu tregon si do te jete pergjigja jone ne kete rast e duam html
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  //dhe fillojme te paraqisim
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println("<html>");
  out.println("<head><title>Servlet JDBC</title></head>");
  out.println("<body>");
  out.println("<h1>Servlet JDBC</h1>");
  out.println("</body></html>");  
  // connecting to database
  //krijon ketu parametrat per tu lidhur me databasin
  Connection con = null;
  Statement st = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;


  try {
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
          out.println(cnfe);

      }
      String url = "mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME";
      con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
      st = con.createStatement();
      rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM servlet"); //shkruan queryn
      // displaying records
      while(rs.next()){ //nderkohe qe ka te dhena nga query jone

      out.print(rs.getObject(1).toString());
      out.print("\t\t\t");
      out.print(rs.getObject(2).toString());
      out.print("<br>");
      }
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
      out.println(ex);
  } finally {
      try {
          if (rs != null) {
              rs.close();
          }
          if (st != null) {
              st.close();
          }
          if (con != null) {
              con.close();
          }

      } catch (SQLException ex) {
          out.println(ex);
      }
  }
}

  }
```

P.s also i have to add that i already tried my project on localhost and it worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't the url be something like:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST + ":" + MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT +
    "/" + MYSQL_DATABASE_NAME;
```

I.e. the protocol is `"jdbc:mysql:"` and the parameters are not (?) substituted automatically in the string...

Comment: Well....im am ashamed ....thank you thats the thing its missing , maybe i worked to much on this project and i can even tell something this simple , in pour words a big thank you :)